# Error of connecting with RASA POST webhook API into React web UI

Tags: reactjs, rest, http-post, rasa

This is a react server-side code to connect the RASA webhook API. I getting status as 0. but in the RASA framework working properly and sending answers for this request. the problem is I can't fetch the rerun answer of the API call.

import React, { Component } from 'react'

```
export const rasaAPI = async function RASA(name, dialogue) {
    // POST request using fetch with error handling

    await fetch('http://192.168.8.100:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'charset':'UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "sender": name, "message": dialogue }),
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok) {
          return response.blob();
      }
      throw new Error(response.status);
     })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(result => {
       console.log('Success:', result);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error('Error:', error);
     });

}
```

This is the console error of the API request.

[image: This is the console error of the API request.]

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer :

React app:
import React, { Component } from 'react'

```
    export const rasaAPI = async function RASA(name, dialogue) {
        // POST request using fetch with error handling
        await fetch('/webhook', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'charset':'UTF-8',
          },
          credentials: "same-origin",
          body: JSON.stringify({ "sender": name, "message": dialogue }),
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(massage => {
        console.log(massage);
      });
    
    }
```

ADD Url into package.json file.

[image: ADD Url into package.json file.]